# Jquery duplicate section onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how I could add another `section` whenever a user starts to type inside of an input in the last-child section.

Essentially what this would look like to the end user is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWIxT.jpg

The part I am having trouble understanding is twofold:

1. How do I duplicate an entire `section` using Javascript?
2. How would I rename the input with a unique name each time the duplication happens? ie: `<input name='attach[2][title]' type='text'>`
3. How do I only duplicate a section when a new one is needed? There should never be multiple blank sections.

I have started out this far, but I am stuck. Any advice would be appreciated!!

```js
  $(".attachments section input").change(function(){
    // Start duplicating
  });
```

```css
.modal {display: block !Important}

.modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 20;
   right: 0; top: 0;
   width: 100%; height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation-duration: 0.4s}

.assignment-window{
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw; height: 85vh;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 2.5fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "asstop asstop"
    "assnav asscontent"}


/* ----------[ASS TOP]---------- */
.asstop {
  grid-area: asstop;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #581F98;}

.asstop .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;}

.asstop .title input {
  flex: 1 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}

.asstop select {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}

.asstop button {
  margin-top: -5px;}


/* ----------[ASS NAV]---------- */
.assnav {
  grid-area: assnav;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 10%;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray}

.assnav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none}

.assnav li {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;}
  .assnav li:hover {background-color: #F2F2F2}
  .assnav li.active {background-color: #EEEEEE}


/* ----------[ASS CONTENT]---------- */
.asscontent {
  grid-area: asscontent;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

.asscontent input, .asscontent select {
  flex: 1;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray}

/* ==== Basic Styling ==== */
.asscontent .basic {display: none}

.asscontent .basic textarea {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

.asscontent .basic .config {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 20px;}
  .asscontent .basic input {text-align: center;}
  .asscontent .basic .points {width: 80px;}

/* ==== Attachment Styling ==== */
.asscontent .attachments section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="assignment-window">
    <div class='asstop'>
      <div class='title'>
        <select>
          <option>✏️</option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type assignment title..' value=''>
        <button class='button purple-btn'>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='assnav'>
      <ul>
        <li>Basic Setup</li>
        <li>Attachments</li>
        <li>Advanced Settings</li>
        <li>Delete Assignment</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='asscontent'>
      <div class='attachments'>
        <section>
          <div class='displayName'>
            <span> Title: </span>
            <input name='attach[1][title]' type='text'>
          </div>
          <div class='url'>
            <span>URL: <span>
            <input name='attach[1][url]' type='url'>
          </div>
          <div class='visible'>
            <span>Visible: <span>
            <select name='attach[1][visible]'>
              <option>- All Students -</option>
              <option> Reading/Social</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Mathew
Let me understand your point. You want to add new section (combination of title, url and visible) when user start typing in the url input. 

Right?

Comment: check out the jQuery clone() method. PS: the event listeners are not cloned.

Comment: @Harry exactly! And I want to make sure that the name of each input is changed with a new identifier as well, so I can properly process the data with PHP after the user submits the form. IE: ```<input name='attach[1][title]' type='text'>``` would change to ```<input name='attach[2][title]' type='text'>``` when the duplication happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the section using the jQuery `clone()` method, add the change event listener to it and modify the name attribute of each one of its `<input>` and `<select>` elements. The number inside that attribute's value will be increased by 1.

```js
function appendSection() {
  $(this).off('change');
  const newSection = $(this).closest('section').clone();
  newSection.find('input, select').each((i, el) => {
    el.value = '';
    el.name = el.name.replace(/\[(\d)\]/, (match, p1) => `[${parseInt(p1) + 1}]`);
  });
  newSection.on('change', appendSection);
  $('.attachments').append(newSection);
}

$(".attachments section input").change(appendSection);
```

```css
.modal {
  display: block !Important
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

.assignment-window {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 85vh;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 2.5fr;
  grid-template-areas: "asstop asstop" "assnav asscontent"
}


/* ----------[ASS TOP]---------- */

.asstop {
  grid-area: asstop;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #581F98;
}

.asstop .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.asstop .title input {
  flex: 1 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray
}

.asstop select {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray
}

.asstop button {
  margin-top: -5px;
}


/* ----------[ASS NAV]---------- */

.assnav {
  grid-area: assnav;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 10%;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray
}

.assnav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none
}

.assnav li {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
}

.assnav li:hover {
  background-color: #F2F2F2
}

.assnav li.active {
  background-color: #EEEEEE
}


/* ----------[ASS CONTENT]---------- */

.asscontent {
  grid-area: asscontent;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.asscontent input,
.asscontent select {
  flex: 1;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray
}


/* ==== Basic Styling ==== */

.asscontent .basic {
  display: none
}

.asscontent .basic textarea {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.asscontent .basic .config {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.asscontent .basic input {
  text-align: center;
}

.asscontent .basic .points {
  width: 80px;
}


/* ==== Attachment Styling ==== */

.asscontent .attachments section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://classcolonies.com/resources/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <nav></nav>
</head>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="assignment-window">
    <div class='asstop'>
      <div class='title'>
        <select>
          <option>✏️</option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type assignment title..' value=''>
        <button class='button purple-btn'>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='assnav'>
      <ul>
        <li>Basic Setup</li>
        <li>Attachments</li>
        <li>Advanced Settings</li>
        <li>Delete Assignment</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='asscontent'>
      <div class='attachments'>
        <section>
          <div class='displayName'>
            <span> Title: </span>
            <input name='attach[1][title]' type='text'>
          </div>
          <div class='url'>
            <span>URL: <span>
            <input name='attach[1][url]' type='url'>
          </div>
          <div class='visible'>
            <span>Visible: <span>
            <select name='attach[1][visible]'>
              <option>- All Students -</option>
              <option> Reading/Social</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but the only issue is that a new line is added on EVERY keypress. Example: If you type a title on section 1, then section 2 is logically added. However, if you go back and edit the title in section 1, with section 2 completely blank, section 3 is then created. 

Ideally, the only time a new section would be created is whenever it is needed. I would imagine this to be something along the lines of only adding a new section with a keypress on the last-child section

Comment: @Mathew I've updated my answer. Now, with `$(this).off('change')`, the change event listener will be removed, for example,  from the inputs in section 1 when section 2 is created, so that typing in section 1 inputs will not create a third section.

Comment: I've implemented this but there seems to be an issue with (this) not referencing anything. I added a new post here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69080545/jquery-clone-not-functioning-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment122092238_69080545

Answer (score 0):

Try this one @Mathew

```js
  $('.section-group-js').on('keyup', 'input[type="url"]', function() {

    var section = $(this).closest('section');
    if (section.is(':last-child')) {
      var index = section.data('index');
      var newSection = section.clone();

      newSection.find('input').val('');
      newSection.data('index', index + 1);
      newSection.attr('data-index', index + 1);
      newSection.find(`input[name="attach[${index}][title]"]`).attr('name', `attach[${index+1}][title]`);
      newSection.find(`input[name="attach[${index}][url]"]`).attr('name', `attach[${index+1}][url]`);

      newSection.insertAfter(section);
    }
  })
```

```css
.modal {
  display: block !Important
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 20;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

.assignment-window {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 85vh;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 0.9fr 2.5fr;
  grid-template-areas: "asstop asstop" "assnav asscontent"
}


/* ----------[ASS TOP]---------- */

.asstop {
  grid-area: asstop;
  padding: 24px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #581F98;
}

.asstop .title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.asstop .title input {
  flex: 1 1;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray
}

.asstop select {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray
}

.asstop button {
  margin-top: -5px;
}


/* ----------[ASS NAV]---------- */

.assnav {
  grid-area: assnav;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 10%;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray
}

.assnav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none
}

.assnav li {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
}

.assnav li:hover {
  background-color: #F2F2F2
}

.assnav li.active {
  background-color: #EEEEEE
}


/* ----------[ASS CONTENT]---------- */

.asscontent {
  grid-area: asscontent;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.asscontent input,
.asscontent select {
  flex: 1;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray
}


/* ==== Basic Styling ==== */

.asscontent .basic {
  display: none
}

.asscontent .basic textarea {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.asscontent .basic .config {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.asscontent .basic input {
  text-align: center;
}

.asscontent .basic .points {
  width: 80px;
}


/* ==== Attachment Styling ==== */

.asscontent .attachments section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="assignment-window">
    <div class='asstop'>
      <div class='title'>
        <select>
          <option>✏️</option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
          <option></option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Type assignment title..' value=''>
        <button class='button purple-btn'>Save Changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='assnav'>
      <ul>
        <li>Basic Setup</li>
        <li>Attachments</li>
        <li>Advanced Settings</li>
        <li>Delete Assignment</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='asscontent'>
      <div class='attachments section-group-js'>
        <section data-index="1">
          <div class='displayName'>
            <span> Title: </span>
            <input name='attach[1][title]' type='text'>
          </div>
          <div class='url'>
            <span>URL: <span>
                  <input name='attach[1][url]' type='url'>
                </div>
                <div class='visible'>
                  <span>Visible: <span>
                  <select name='attach[1][visible]'>
                    <option>- All Students -</option>
                    <option> Reading/Social</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: @Mathew I have created this solution as per your need. It will add new section only when you type something in URL input and it will create every time new index for your duplicated inputs.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: whenever I use this and send the information to a PHP script, there is nothing output beyond the first section. I found this info from using ```print_r($_POST)```. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hey @Mathew, How you are submitting your form?? Are you using save changes button ?? 
If so, make sure all sections should be wrap with one form which you are submitting to PHP script.

If you found anything useful here, you can up-vote me. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes I am submitting with the save changes button. It is not working though, I am not sure why.